# Ceasar's cipher in python

Tags: python, caesar-cipher

i'm making a simple program for translating text with Ceasar's cipher. Here is my code.

```
alphabet = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"]
text = "hello how are you"
text = text.split(" ")
new_text_array = []
key = 3
for w in range(len(text)):
    new_word_array = []
    word = list(text[w])
    for i in range(len(word)):
        if word[i] in alphabet:
            new_index = alphabet.index(word[i]) + key
            if new_index > 25:
                new_index -= 26
            new_word_array += alphabet[new_index]
    new_word = ''.join(new_word_array)
    print(new_word)
    new_text_array += new_word
    print(new_text_array)
new_text = ' '.join(new_text_array)
print(new_text)
```

When i run the code, on line 20, it correctly prints ciphered word as a string, but on line 21, where i'm adding words to array, it adds each letter as an individual item in array instead of adding whole word. I'm still fairly new to python, what am i missing? Please help. Sorry for my english, hope you'll understand what i'm trying to say.

Comment: Replace `+=` with `append(..)`...

Comment: Thank you  for quick reply. It works perfectly. Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `new_text_array.append(new_word)`.

In `new_text_array += new_word` the `+=` means that you are adding all elements of the second array to the first array, so the Python iterates over `new_word`, because string can also be iterated over with `new_word[x]`, and adds all its elements (letters here) as separate elements.

Another option here is `new_text_array += [new_word]`, where you just put `new_word` into the array as the only element

Comment: Thanks for explanation, makes sense.